# Use Excel/VB to create a list of product variations based parent products

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a shopify store and I have 3 product variations i.e. size/colour/customisation location which I need to split to create a line for each potential variant.

An example of my sheet is included below. I can provide the excel if easier.

[image: Example]

I hope I am explaining correctly.

I am hoping to achieve for the first example, the tshirt would have a Small option, in black with the customisation location left breast
then next line would have Small option, in black with the customisation location right breast and so on.

I am a novice so any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think the easiest is to avoid VBA, use PowerQuery (Split those 3 columns by character into rows) and you can re-use the resulting M-code. If VBA, then see @Pᴇʜ his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 nested loops for that.
Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExampleGenerateUniquePermutations()
    Dim ArraySize() As Variant
    ArraySize = Array("S", "M", "L")

    Dim ArrayColor() As Variant
    ArrayColor = Array("red", "green")

    Dim ArrayVariation() As Variant
    ArrayVariation = Array("left", "right", "extra", "nonsense")

    Dim Size As Variant
    For Each Size In ArraySize

        Dim Color As Variant
        For Each Color In ArrayColor

            Dim Variation As Variant
            For Each Variation In ArrayVariation
                Debug.Print Size, Color, Variation
            Next Variation

        Next Color

    Next Size

End Sub
```

The output will be

```
S             red           left
S             red           right
S             red           extra
S             red           nonsense
S             green         left
S             green         right
S             green         extra
S             green         nonsense
M             red           left
M             red           right
M             red           extra
M             red           nonsense
M             green         left
M             green         right
M             green         extra
M             green         nonsense
L             red           left
L             red           right
L             red           extra
L             red           nonsense
L             green         left
L             green         right
L             green         extra
L             green         nonsense
```

Note that you can easily split your string `"S;M;L;XL"` into an array using the split function `ArraySize = Split("S;M;L;XL", ";")`